# Checking if an index exists in a non-optional Array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, option-type

I have this array:

```
var currentTouches = [UITouch]()
```

At any point, it may contain 0-5 `UITouch`es. I want to check each index and do something with the content if it exists.

**But I cannot find a way to check without getting an error.** The problem seems to be, that `UITouch` isn't an optional, so I can't just ask if it is `nil`.

What do I do? I tried making it an optional, but that makes much of my other code unusual. Surely there must be a simple solution.

Comment: `for (index, touch) in currentTouches.enumerated() { // handle touch at index }`

Comment: You can check if the **index** of a particular touch item is `nil` rather than the item itself.

Comment: If `currentTouches` is an array of `UITouch`, to check if an object exists at a given index all you need to check is `currentTouches.count > index`.

Comment: Are you talking about `estimationUpdateIndex`?

Answer (score 2):

The valid indices of `currentTouches` are simply `currentTouches.indices`.  So to check if an index `i` is valid, you could check `if currentTouches.indices.contains(i)`.  You could also check `if i < currentTouches.count` (assuming you already know that `i >= 0`).

An easier way of doing that would be to just loop on the valid indices and handle each in turn:

```
for index in currentTouches.indices {
    // handle value at index
}
```

Or if you don't care about the indices:

```
for touch in currentTouches {
    // handle touch
}
```

Even better is to use `enumerated()` which gives you a tuple containing the index and value:

```
for (index, touch) in currentTouches.enumerated() {
    // handle touch at index
}
```